# AngularJS: ng-option with key value - updating object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-option to update my model data. But I am not able to see my selection when selecting last option from dropdown list for the first time. However in the code my model is holding that selected item.

My html:

```
<select class="form-control" name="myField" ng-model="myField" ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in fieldFieldOptions" ng-required="myAllFiles=='NO'"/></select>

 controller-
 $scope.fieldFieldOptions = [];
 $scope.fieldFieldOptions = result.data;[contains drop down list]
```

`$scope.myFIeld` contains my selected item from dropdown list.

What i am doing wrong in this specific case?

Comment: provide your code on plunker

Comment: what is the structure of `result.data`?

Comment: result.data: Object
    firstName: "6"
    lastName: "8"
          Id: "19"
     select:"10"

Comment: it is stored as key-value pair

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet with ngOptions:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myField;

  result = {};
  result.data = {
    "key1": {
      firstName: "6",
      lastName: "8",
      Id: "19",
      select: "10"
    },
    "key2": {
      firstName: "1",
      lastName: "11",
      Id: "39",
      select: "11"
    },
    "key3": {
      firstName: "2",
      lastName: "22",
      Id: "29",
      select: "12"
    }
  };

  $scope.fieldFieldOptions = result.data;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div>
    <select class="form-control" name="myField" ng-model="myField" 
    ng-options="key as key for (key, item) in fieldFieldOptions" 
    ng-required="myAllFiles=='NO'">
    </select>
  </div>
  <pre>fieldFieldOptions = {{fieldFieldOptions | json}}</pre>
  <pre>myField = {{myField | json}}</pre>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the structure of result.data similar to yours (associative array)?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myField;

  result = {};
  result.data = {
      firstName: "6",
      lastName: "8",
      Id: "19",
      select: "10"  
  };

  $scope.fieldFieldOptions = result.data;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div>
    <select class="form-control" name="myField" ng-model="myField" 
    ng-options="key as key for (key, item) in fieldFieldOptions" 
    ng-required="myAllFiles=='NO'">
    </select>
    <pre>myField = {{myField | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```